# use prestashop module in a codeigniter php website

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, prestashop-1.7

I used to have a prestashop site then I changed for a codeigniter site but I wanted to keep a prestashop module (a product configurator) so I kept the prestashop site in a subdirectory /my-site.com/prestashop
with a call of the module in index.php

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/prestashop/config/config.inc.php')) {
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/prestashop/config/config.inc.php');
    if (Module::isEnabled('itemstyle')) {
        Module::getInstanceByName('itemstyle');
    }
}
```

this worked very well.
Then, I switched my codeigniter site to php7.4 which is not compatible with my prestashop1.7 anymore.
So I moved my-site.com/prestashop to a subdomain prestashop.my-site.com to be able to use different versions of php.

Now when I try to access prestahop/my-site.com, I am systematically redirected to the old my-site.com/prestashop...there is probably a configuration file that makes this redirection. The owner of the module had made changes for me but I can't find in which files?
Would you have an idea because I don't know prestashop very well

Ok for redirection.

---

Now I have the following error :

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'xxxxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.fr/prestashop.xxxxxx.fr/modules/itemstyle/core/ItemStyleCore.php on line 602\nPHP message: PHP Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/prestashop.xxxxxxx.fr/modules/itemstyle/core/ItemStyleCore.php
```

And I am sure database information are correct in my app/config/parameters.php

end this error when going to admin interface

```
2008#0: *212754 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SmartyException: unable to write file /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/prestashop.xxxxx.fr/app/cache/prod/smarty/compile/53/31/59/wrt6405c290896b58_49515250 in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.fr/prestashop.xxxxxxx.fr/vendor/prestashop/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php:46
```

Comment: What is the question? How to use a Prestashop module in CodeIgniter (which most likely requires you to rewrite it, but hard to say since we know nothing about the module) or how to fix the redirect issue that Prestashop redirects to the "old" URL (which also is hard to help with since we have _no idea_ how things are set up) ?

Comment: I really hope that this is just a short-term fix while you work on a longer-term solution. PHP 7.4 hasn't been supported by security fixes for the last 3 months, and it will continue to get more dangerous as the months and years go by. If your prestashop module doesn't even support 7.4, I shudder to think about the old security vulnerabilities that may be present on your prestashop subdomain. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Thank you indeed, first of all I would like to solve this redirection problem. 
prestashop.my-site.com redirects to my-site.com/prestashop (which has been deleted)

Answer (score 0):

After every domain / folder change you have to rectify your domain value in backoffice under the **Shop Parameters > Traffic & SEO** menu.

Make sure to fix the "**Shop Domain" / "Shop SSL Domain**" entries with the actual domain, and fix the URI value from **/prestashop/** to **/** (since you're not having a subfolder anymore).

Make sure to Save your modification, so the main Prestashop .htaccess file will be regenerated with the new redirects.

If you cannot access your backoffice from new environment, just use PhpMyAdmin or a MySql client and  perform those modifications directly in the  **ps_shop_url** DB table.